# Подключение плагина csscomb-group-size к csscomb в grunt

Tags: javascript, плагин, grunt

Сталкивался ли кто с этим плагином,может кто напишет пошаговую инструкцию для этого?
Из того что я нашел это [сам плагин](https://github.com/tonyganch/csscomb-group-size) и небольшой кусок на  [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/230589/) об этом:

> Например, вот опция, которая убирает пустую строку между группами деклараций, если деклараций в группе слишком мало. Подключить плагин довольно просто, для этого есть метод `use()`:

```
var CSScomb = require('csscomb');
var groupSize = require('csscomb-group-size');

// Число 4 означает, что если в группе меньше 4 деклараций, между этой
// группой и предыдущей уберётся пустая строка-разделитель:
var config = { 'group-size': 4 };

// Создаём новый экземпляр «расчёски»:
var csscomb = new CSScomb().use(groupSize).configure(config);

// Творим чудеса:
csscomb.processPath('path/to/css');
```

И если честно понятней мне от этого не стало....Куда ложить плагин? Что за метод `use()`? Вообще в каких файлах все это ковырять?

Comment: так а с чем конкретно проблемы?

Comment: @ Grundy, проблема в том, что я не понимаю как его подключить... Вот и спрашиваю может кто объяснит?  
На данном этапе у меня есть архив с плагином...а куда ложить файлы? И где искать метод USE(), И что делать с куском кода приведенным выше хз.....